# Recursive Function Scanning String to Add ASCII

Tags: c++, string, recursion

So I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

> Write a recursive function that will sum all of the char's within a C String.

I'm a little rusty in doing this normally, but I finally got it to work with a normal for loop:

```
int countstr(string s)
{ 
int sum = 0;

  if(s.length() == 0)
    {
    exit(0);
    }
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) 
     {
         sum += s[i];
         }
 return sum;

}
```

I can then go inside main and do this:

```
int main ()
{
  cout << "This word adds up to " << countstr("HELLO") << " in ASCII " << endl;
}
```

and everything works as it should, counting and adding up the characters in the string via their ASCII numbers. 
The problem I'm having is trying to figure out how this is typed up so it works recursively. I know I need to forgo the for loop in lieu of calling up the function itself, but I don't know what to use instead of the sum += s[i]; that I have going in my for loop. I've been looking around in the C string library, but I don't see anything that can replace the [i] that the for loop calls up. Does anyone know what I should be using to do this? I'm not looking for an answer in code, just need help in what I should be using to make this happen.

Comment: isnt a c string a char*?

Comment: exit(0) in case of empty string? It's nonsense, just return 0 is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of many ways to do it.

```
int reccountstr(string s, int i){
  if(s.size() == i)
    return (0 + s[i]);
  else
    return reccountstr(s, i + 1) + s[i];
}
```

And then in main you just call it with a zero initial argument.

```
cout << "This word adds up to " << reccountstr("HELLO", 0) << " in ASCII " << endl;
```

Comment: So basically you keep calling the function until you reach the end.  And then the recursion comes back.  Adding each step during the way.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, and it's what I was trying to figure out. I wasn't sure if using the int i in the function call would work. The only part I don't understand is why the +1 is neded, what does that do?

Comment: The + 1 is so that when you call the function again then it will move to the next letter in the word.  So the first time you call the function you are on the letter "H" from "HELLO".  The second time you call it you are on the "E" and so on.  Finally when you are on the letter "O" you start adding up the corresponding ASCII values and when you start returning values they get added to the value in the function that called it first.  As a rule of thumb, if you are using a "counter" variable in your for loop.  All you have to do is call the recursive function again with a "counter + 1" value.

Answer (score 3):

Skeleton could be like this:

```
int countlen(const char * str)
{
    if (condition)
        return 0;
    else
        return *str + countlen(str + 1);
}
```

The rest is up to you :)

Comment: `return *str + countlen(str + 1)`, I think.

Comment: Is char considered a C version of a C++ string? I've seen some uses of this in recursion with strings, but haven't understood why using a char is preferred over a string

Comment: Yes, C strings are represented by 'char[]', 'char *' and 'const char *'. Your assigment says explicitly to use C string, not C++ one ('std::string').

Answer (score 1):

```
int countString(char sample[], int i)
{
    if(sample[i] == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return(1 + countString(sample, i+1));
}
```

This could be one solution, where if the current character read is not null (0, or '\0') it will return `1 + countString(sample, i + 1)` where `i` is the current character index to be read.

Once it reaches null it returns 0. So for a character length of three, it will do 1 + 1 + 1 + 0. You can call the function with `printf("%d\n", countString(yourStringName, 0))`.

1. So your base case here is `character[index] == empty`
2. Your inductive case is `1 + function(stringName, index + 1)`, roughly speaking.

Also, this is a little outside the scope of your question, but you can also make this more efficient by avoiding constantly building up the stack. A way to do this is to create another variable inside the function that continuously accumulates the total count. For more info on this see this link on `tail recursion:`
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion

---

**More memory conservative version:**

```
int countString(char sample[], int i, int total)
{
    if(sample[i] == 0)
        return total;
    else
        return countString(sample, i+1, ++total);
}
```

You can call this with `printf("%d\n", countString(sample, 0, 0));`